# ShimSPWeb().LocaleGet not available?

Tags: unit-testing, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-fakes, shim

I've been starting to look into the new feature in VisualStudio 2012 where you can add a fake assembly of a dll for unit testing purpose.
I'm working with SharePoint 2010 and we all now it is a pain to unit test code that depend on the SharePoint API.

I added a fake assembly for Microsoft.SharePoint and that worked fine, but I came to a point where I need to override the method `SPWeb.Locale`. I thought that would be easy. I thought there would be a method like `ShimSPWeb.LocaleGet` but there is not.

This is the only options I have regarding `Locale` on my `ShimSPWeb`

[image]

In short: There should be a `shimWeb.LocaleGet` available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. You can add diagnostics to the *.fakes settings file. This enables debugging output when generating the fakes assembly.

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/" Diagnostic="true">
```

When I did this, I got this output:

> unstubbable: method is abstract and could not be stubbed, type
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo is not available in the target
>   framework version

SharePoint 2010 targets .Net version 3.5. My unit test was set to target framework .Net 4.0.
I changed the target of my unit test project to 3.5, regenerated the fake assembly and voila! It worked!